# REST API: INVALID_TYPE error while querying a custom object

Tags: rest-api

I tried to query a set of objects using REST API. But when I query a custom object I am getting the following error.

> [{"message":"\nselect id from test_object3__c\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'test_object3\__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]

PS: I use describeGlobalSObjects() to get the object names, the object status is deployed and I have access to the object.

**UPDATED**

I have a list of object names stored in **lstObjects** and I am hitting the REST API to get the record count of each object.

```
foreach (string ObjectName in lstObjNames) {
    jsonResult = HttpGet(token.instance_url + @"/services/data/v26.0/query/?q=select+id+from+" + ObjectName, "");
    lstJsonResult.Add(jsonResult);
    RecordCount = FetchValuefromJSON(jsonResult);
}
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: could you please add some code ?are you using standard REST API?

Comment: is there a namespace?

Comment: @user227: No, there is no namespace.

Comment: @MohithKumar: Updated the question.

Comment: Do you get anything at this url "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Test_Object3__c"? If not do you see the object at this url "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects"?